# Save the result of a method in a class

Tags: javascript, class, random, properties

I want to save or store the outcome of a property in a class to use in another property in the same class. How do I do that?

for example:

````
class MyClass {

  get randomNumber() {
    let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1
    return number
  }

  get newSum() {
    return this.randomNumber + 1 // I want to use the result from the previous property and add 1 to that
  }

}

```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instantly call the `randomNumber` getter in the `constructor`. The `contructor` is called when you use the `new` keyword to create an instance of `MyClass`.

The `newSum` getter now returns the stored random number `+ 1`.

Though, I would recommend not using the getter pattern for the `newSum` property as a getter should not be used to mutate values. Instead make it a proper method.

```js
class MyClass {

  constructor() {
    this.number = this.randomNumber;
  }

  get randomNumber() {
    let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1
    return number
  }

  newSum() {
    return this.number += 1;
  }

}

const instance = new MyClass();
console.log(instance.number); // The random starting number.
console.log(instance.newSum()); // +1
console.log(instance.newSum()); // +1
console.log(instance.newSum()); // +1
```

Comment: He wants the value from the `randomNumber` getter to be used in the second getter when incrementing it. Perhaps I'm reading your code wrong, but I don't think it achieves that.

Comment: @Youssef, it does just that.